# Протокол для пересылки данных

Tags: c#

Что посоветуете использовать для того, чтобы с разных пк пересылать нужную мне информацию на 1 нужный мне пк - данными являются список Assambly из приложение - желательно чтобы обрабатывало все подключения,а не по одному

Comment: Если речь идет о сервере и нескольких клиентах, и вам нужна модель запрос-ответ, то я бы воспользовался WCF, а транспорт бы уже выбирал какой нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Ок, внесу свои 5 копеек. 
Есть такая штука - WCF https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf
Она очень такая высокоуровневая. В ней вы указываете интерфейсы взаимодействия клиента и сервера, потом на сервере и клиенте пишете реализацию. 
А вот транспорт, который будет использоваться, вы можете указать в конфигурации. Это может быть и Http, и шифрованный Http, и очередь сообщений MSMQ, и именованные каналы и многое другое.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в сторону [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). В ней уже отработаны многие ситуации касаемо подключения, разрыва связи и т.д., есть различные виды передачи данных.

Либо просто посмотри в сторону MQ(Messaging Queue) систем. Благо сейчас их выбор хороший и информации предостаточно.

Comment: Например, доступный в винде как компонент MSMQ. Только я не уверен, что автору нужна такая модель, мож ему просто запрос-ответ нужен.

Comment: @tym32167, просто запрос-ответ в zeromq тоже есть, repreq называется. :) Автору можно многими инструментами организовать, я просто предложил один из них. Я не так давно им пользовался, удобная вещь.

Comment: Ну я про то, что перед тем, как добавлять новый узел в системе, лучше проверить, может, можно и без него обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

Вы описали клиент-серверную архитектуру, для которой подойдёт любой протокол транспортного уровня и выше. В общем случае используется HTTP и задача решается созданием веб-приложения с REST API, принимающего данные от клиентов, которые шлют HTTP-запросы.

Если все компьютеры находятся в локальной сети или IP адрес принимающего компьютера всегда известен, а структура данных простая, то проще использовать TCP соединение. В данном случае Вам поможет класс `TcpListener`, пример параллельной работы [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102573/3100967), обычно используется второй пример из приведённых автором.

ZeroMQ будет хорошим простым решением, особенно, если вам требуется коммуникация в обе стороны от клиента к серверу и наоборот. Но если Вы работаете с C#, там настройка коммуникации через TCP-сокеты не сложнее настройки ZeroMQ.